# Sitecore Statistics for item copied / duplicated

Tags: content-management

The items that are newly created by copying or duplicating have the same Statistics (Created Date, Created By, Updated Date, Updated By, Revision) as their originals. The same happens with their children items that were copied or duplicated together with them.

When researched, found a blog that provides an [ItemCopiedEventHandler workaroun](https://www.coria.com/en/insights/blog/Sitecore/sitecore-content-sync-and-the-update-date-problem)d; however it was designed for an older version of Sitecore(8.0). We are currently in 9.3.

Can anyone share your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing really changed between version 8.0 and 9.3 when it comes to statistics of Sitecore items.

When you copy items, values like "Created" are not updated.

So if you need them to be updated, you should write your custom code or use the code from the blog post you found.

Comment: Thanks @Marek. Wonder if there is an easy way apart from writing custom code.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way without custom code.

Comment: Thank you @Marek. Grateful for your replies.